# KitKat Connection from URL get NullPointerException in AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, nullpointerexception

i'm new in java and android programming but i accepted a challenge launched by a friend and now i have to work hard.

I finally managed to have this type of activity working with AsyncTask but it seems to work well on all android but not on 4.4.2 KitKat.

The problem seems to be on url.openConnection and i tried many times to change the way in wich i do it but i haven't had positive results...
I have only to read  file from an URL
This is my class code:

```
public class MenuActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);

        new HttpTask().execute();
    }

    public final class HttpTask
            extends
            AsyncTask<String/* Param */, Boolean /* Progress */, String /* Result */> {

        private HttpClient mHc = new DefaultHttpClient();

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            publishProgress(true);
            InputStream inputstream = null;

            URL url = null;
            try {
                url = new URL("http://somesite/prova.txt");
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            assert url != null;
            URLConnection connection = null;
            try {
                connection = url.openConnection();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) connection;
                httpConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                httpConnection.connect();

                if (httpConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    inputstream = httpConnection.getInputStream();
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            ByteArrayOutputStream bytearryoutputstream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            int i;
            try {
                i = inputstream.read();
                while (i != -1) {
                    bytearryoutputstream.write(i);
                    i = inputstream.read();
                }
                inputstream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return bytearryoutputstream.toString();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Boolean... progress) {

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            StringBuilder nuovafrase=new StringBuilder("");

            String[] frasone=result.split("\n");

            ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listViewDemo);

            ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
            arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.rowmenu, R.id.textViewList, frasone);
            listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        }


    }
}
```

And this is the Logcat...

```
03-11 17:49:37.955    1277-1294/com.example.appsb.app W/System.err﹕                 atjava.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
      03-11 17:49:37.955    1277-1294/com.example.appsb.app W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
       03-11 17:49:37.959    1277-1294/com.example.appsb.app W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
       03-11 17:49:37.959    1277-1294/com.example.appsb.app W/System.err﹕ Caused by: libcore.io.GaiException: getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)
         03-11 17:49:37.959    1277-1294/com.example.appsb.app W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.Posix.getaddrinfo(Native Method)
       03-11 17:49:37.959    1277-1294/com.example.appsb.app W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:61)
         03-11 17:49:37.959    1277-1294/com.example.appsb.app W/System.err﹕ at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:405)
      03-11 17:49:37.959    1277-1294/com.example.appsb.app W/System.err﹕ ... 18 more
        03-11 17:49:37.959    1277-1294/com.example.appsb.app W/System.err﹕ Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: getaddrinfo failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
        03-11 17:49:37.959    1277-1294/com.example.appsb.app W/System.err﹕ ... 21 more
         03-11 17:49:37.963    1277-1294/com.example.appsb.app W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4d69b20)
             03-11 17:49:37.963    1277-1294/com.example.appsb.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕               FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
         Process: com.example.appsb.app, PID: 1277
             java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
        at               java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
              at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
             Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                   at          com.example.appsb.app.MenuActivity$HttpTask.doInBackground(MenuActivity.java:74)
                    at com.example.appsb.app.MenuActivity$HttpTask.doInBackground(MenuActivity.java:33)
                   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
                    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
                       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

There is a  Caused by: `java.lang.NullPointerException` but i cannot understand why...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It could be caused by the `inputstream` being `null`. `inputstream` will only be initialized if the response code is `OK`. So you need to check what response code is being returned. If it is not causing the error, I'd still add some code for if the response code is not `OK`. You don't want your app to crash if it can't connect. You should at least display a helpful error message
Example:

```
else{
    showErrorMsg();
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Catch FileNotFoundException when trying inputstream.read();

```
try {
    i = inputstream.read();
    while (i != -1) {
        bytearryoutputstream.write(i);
        i = inputstream.read();
    }
    inputstream.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    Log.e("MyTag","Handling empty page...");
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e("MyTag",e.toString());
}
```